# Free, editable calendar for Wordpress site that using Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, calendar, elementor

I am updating a website that was built (not by me) in Wordpress using Elementor. I'm trying to add a calendar that can list basic events and provide links to them. I found the plugin called "Wordpress Calendar" and have been able to add one of those to the draft of the site, but whenever I right-click on the calendar and choose "edit calendar," a bar pops up on the left hand side of the screen telling me about "user restrictions." So I can't actually add any events to the calendar. I think I have full access to edit the site. Is there a way to bypass Elementor and create the calendar in Wordpress code?

Is there a free way to add an editable calendar? I see this but I'm not sure how to integrate it into the Elementor site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Sorry, I'm new to WP.

Comment: Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In my post, I was trying to troubleshoot specific problems I was having with the Wordpress Calendar and The Events Calendar plugins but I realize my title made it sound like I was asking for recommendations so I will delete this post. Thanks for the links - for future reference, are there guidelines for how to create a "reproducible example" with something like WP or Elementor that's more drag-and-drop than code-based?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

1- Install that plugin you have found https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

2- Visit this page https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/embedding-calendar-views-with-the-tribe_events-shortcode/ and get the shortcode you need. The shortcode will display the calendar you want on any page you place the shortcode in.

3- Insert the shortcode within Elementor builder: just add a new "Shortcode" element and insert the shortcode you need into it.

Note: the calendar can only be edited by you in the backend.

Comment: It looks like that shortcode is only available with a "Pro" paid membership - correct?

Comment: no, you can just insert it inside an HTML element or code  element.

Comment: Your contributions are welcome, but please note that answering off-topic questions like this is against Stack Overflow guidelines. Otherwise we are just encouraging more poor questions :) Your answer could even get downvoted, even if it is good! 
Please see the "**Answer well-asked questions**" section in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Instead you should flag off-topic questions, or if it is low quality & needs more details then ask for more information in the comments. Or simply just move on to well-asked questions :)